# Infinite scroll on both directions without a browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to implement an infinite vertical and horizontal scrolling on a site, I'm working on something similar to Google Maps.

With a drag-and-drop interface, I'm able to navigate page that contains Divs and Images.

Are there any plugins that will allow me to get started with a base?

Comment: If you're able to navigate using drag & drop then why you need a plugin? Just use Drag & Drop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery, the general idea is like this:

- Hide scrollbars with css `body{overflow:hidden}`, `#your_div{overflow:hidden}` or whatever you are using
- [Detect drag/move/release and use correct callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127118/can-you-detect-dragging-in-jquery)

You may also be interested in [the mousewheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

Answer (score 0):

Use {overflow:hidden} with your div or full body. Place it where you want to scroll infinite.

Other way just check this link for horizontal scrolling infinite :

[Infinite Horizontal Scrolling Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889793/infinite-horizontal-scrolling-div?rq=1)

Comment: once check this link hope it will help you : http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars